# Communication between states in AWS Step Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

In AWS Step Functions I can create a state machine (workflow) where each state is for example an AWS Lambda function. The input and output of each state (i.e., Lambda function) is a JSON object that passes from the preceding state to the next. I was wondering whether this JSON is passed to and received from each state by the AWS Step Functions orchestrator. That is, there is no actual communication between the states (Lambda functions) of the workflow, but rather the communication is always between the orchestrator and each state (Lambda function). Is that correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in AWS is Event Driven - and those Events are in the form of a JSON object. When a given Lambda in a State Machine returns from its Invocation, depending on the structure of the State Machine Definition it either appends its result as a new key to the original input Event, creates a new Json Object with the key defined from the state machine definition and discards the original event, or chooses a key out of the Invocation response (assuming it is in a json format) that it can either append or replace to the original event.

That event is then directed to the next Task in your State Machine - be that a lambda or an API Call, or a Choice or a Parallel or whatever. That event is passed directly into that next task - if it is a Lambda for instance, the Lambda Hander function will receive the event (along with a State Machine specific context object) that will be processed by the lambda as however you coded it.

As to dive a little more into your question, I *think* what you are asking is if this is the flow of an event:

```
Lambda -> State Machine systems -> Lambda -> State Machine Systems -> ect
```

or if its:

```
State Machine (Lambda -> Lambda -> ect)
```

**Officially**? It's the first version. Lambda's are designed with the idea they will be Stateless - and not recall information from other lambda invokes or their own (In practice its not this perfect, but thats another topic). State Machines are specifically called that because they manage "State" of data between Lambda invokes. So yes, they are handling the data between lambdas.

**In Practice?** .... it doesn't matter which it is. You can't direct the the State machine to do anything with the event other than the above described actions I mentioned - and those are set in the State Machine Definition. You have no access to the backend of State Machine that would do the handling described in the top example other than through the set at deployment time definition.

so while the official process *is* the first version - the state machine does take the event, manipulate it, and then pass it on to the next lambda - in practice it doesn't change how you as a developer interact with the system.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications, they are really helpful!

Comment: my pleasure. It's a complicated subject that works in ways that most 'conventional' pre cloud structures don't - but once you figure it out, its pretty easy to keep in your head.